# Does wsdl4J supports to resolve HTTP bindings?

Tags: java, wsdl, wsdl4j

My wsdl contains SOAP11,SOAP12 and HTTP bindings.
When i try to retrieve the Address Location from the HTTPBinding, my sample code block throws error

> ."Unsupported wsdl errors!"

(i used wsdl4j to read the wsdl)

My sample code to retrieve AddressLocation is as follows;

```
private String getAddressUrl(ExtensibilityElement exElement) throws APIManagementException {

        if (exElement instanceof SOAP12AddressImpl) {
            return ((SOAP12AddressImpl) exElement).getLocationURI();
        } else if (exElement instanceof SOAPAddressImpl) {
            return ((SOAPAddressImpl) exElement).getLocationURI();
        } else {
            String msg = "Unsupported WSDL errors!";
            log.error(msg);
            throw new APIManagementException(msg);
        }
    }
```

Here i see only "SOAP12AddressImpl" and "SOAPAddressImpl" are available in the WSDL4J. So, when i pass HTTPbinding data, above code throws error.
My sample HTTP binding extensibility element is;

```
HTTPAddress ({http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/}address):
required=null
locationURI=http://10.100.1.35:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService.SimpleStockQuoteServiceHttpEndpoint.
```

How can i read address location from HTTPBinding ? is there implementation available in the wsdl4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my bad; HTTP addressimplementaion also available in wsdl4j.
Corrected my code like this;

```
if (exElement instanceof SOAP12AddressImpl) {
            return ((SOAP12AddressImpl) exElement).getLocationURI();
        } else if (exElement instanceof SOAPAddressImpl) {
            return ((SOAPAddressImpl) exElement).getLocationURI();
        } else if (exElement instanceof HTTPAddressImpl) {
            return ((HTTPAddressImpl) exElement).getLocationURI();
        } else {
            String msg = "Unsupported WSDL errors!";
            log.error(msg);
            throw new APIManagementException(msg);
        }
```